# Retornar ID do Local apenas com Latitude e Longitude - Google Maps JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps-javascript-api

Boa noite, minha dúvida se refere ao seguinte caso:

Estou trabalhando com a API do google maps V3, e utilizo serviços como o Places, Geocoder e Matrix Distance. Porém tenho um enorme problema para retornar o ID do local atual do usuário (retornado utilizando o geolocation do maps), porém ele me retorna apenas  a Latitude e Longitude do local, ou eu não estou sabendo retornar outras informações.

```
        if (navigator.geolocation) { 
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        posAtual = { // recebe ltd e lngt
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        };

        var openedMarker = posAtual.lat + "<br>" + posAtual.lng;


      var markerAtual = addMarker({coords:posAtual, content:openedMarker}); // define o local do marker

      map.setCenter(posAtual); // centraliza posição atual se permitido pelo browser

      }, function() {
        handleLocationError(true, markerAtual, map.getCenter()); // se der erro volta pra localização antiga

      });
    return true;
    } else {
      // Browser doesn't support Geolocation ou NÃO foi aceito pelo user
      handleLocationError(false, markerAtual, map.getCenter());

    return false;
    }
    function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) { //Erro que sera exibido caso falhe
    infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
    infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                          'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                          'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');

}
```

Esse é o código que utilizo para buscar a posição atual, ja tentei buscar na documentação do google ou mesmo aqui no SO, mas sem muito sucesso.

A API retorna o ID do Local sempre que é pesquisado, no caso, com um campo place autocomplete. Mas não acontece ao buscar uma coordenada Latitude/Longitude.

Agradeço a atenção.

Comment: Poderia colocar uma url de exemplo?